# Woocommerce update sku of all products? filter?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to set the SKU to the ID of the product.. but cannot find the right filter to use?

Is there a filter that sends the product SKU?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_sku', 'update_sku', 10, 1);

function update_sku( $sku ){

//set $newsku as product id


    return $newsku;
}
```

How do i accomplish this?  I have 1000s of products without a SKU.  I've tried a plugin called SKU generator but that doesn't work.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by adding following code to your `functions.php` file and after adding go to you site `example.com` for only once.

After that remove below code from the `functions.php`.

```
    add_filter( 'init', 'update_sku', 10, 1);

    function update_sku( $sku ){

        $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => 12
                );
        $i=0;
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                $random_sku = mt_rand(100000, 999999);

                update_post_meta($loop->post->ID,'_sku',$random_sku);

                $i++;
            endwhile;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
```

**NOTE :** If you don't remove after one use, products SKU will change everytime you visit any page of your site.

Comment: Just add some parameter check in you function like if(isset(request param)) then do the update will do it.

Comment: He just want to set SKU for once.So no need to get into more :)

Comment: Thanks for this i'll try this out on my website.

Comment: Make sure you have database back up before implementing code.

Comment: Why would the SKU change if i left the code in functions.php?  Product ID's aren't dynamic?

Comment: Oh  i see you used random.  My original idea was just to use the Product ID as the SKU.

Comment: Because the code in `functions.php` will call every time when you visit any of your page. And We have used `update_post_meta` function here **WITHOUT ANY CONDITION** .. So every time it will update product SKU if you do not remove after use.

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner Hi, I am trying to generate SKU for the product which is added by Dokan plugin, so your script will useful if its generate permanent sku after added product, I search plugins & scripts for that, but its not usful because they are mainly based on woocommerce so its not helpful for me. is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Add it as shortcode and make SKU same as Product id.

```
add_shortcode( 'update_sku', 'update_sku', 10, 1);

function update_sku( $sku ){

    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 12
            );
    $i=0;
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

            

            update_post_meta($loop->post->ID,'_sku',$loop->post->ID);

            $i++;
        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Then use this shortcode in a page and open it once. so it will not re-create sku's every time.