# Woocommerce SKU Generator: Generate a sku for all variations same as parent sku

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, sku

i need a simply function that allow me to add or replace empty sku code for variation in my published product with parent sku of product.

is there a way to obtain this work?

Comment: i disabled unique sku! i need it to make functionant wp lister...infact i use sku as ean, so sku on all variations are imported by wp-lister on ebay as ean variable product

Comment: i found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670292/woocommerce-update-sku-of-all-products-filter/47955472#47955472 but i need only for variations and all sku already charged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:** To replace empty SKU code for variation in your published product with the parent SKU *(the variable product SKU)*, try this function that will **only work for admin user role**.

> **Do a database backup before runing this**

To run this function, **browse your shop page**:

- It will update 2500 empty variations SKU each time.
- A message will display the count of updated variations.
- Each time you will need to reload the page to process 2000 variations SKUs.,

When all variations SKUs will be updated, a message let you know that the job is done.

The code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'update_variations_sku', 100 );
function update_variations_sku(){
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $results2 = array();
    $limit = 2500; // Number of variations to process

    // The SQL query (get the variations with empty sku and their parent product ID)
    $query = $wpdb->get_results( "
        SELECT p.ID, p.post_parent
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_type LIKE 'product_variation'
        AND p.post_status LIKE 'publish'
        AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_sku'
        LIMIT $limit
    " );

    if( count($query) == 0 ){
        echo "<p><pre>The job is finished, you can remove the code</pre></p>";
        return; // exit
    }

    // Loop through variation Ids and get the parent variable product ID
    foreach( $query as $value )
        $results[$value->post_parent][] = $value->ID;

    // Loop through variation Ids and set the parent sku in related empty variations skus
    foreach($results as $parent_id => $variation_ids){
        $parent_sku = get_post_meta( $parent_id, '_sku', true );
        $count = 0;
        foreach($variation_ids as $variation_id){
            $count++;
            update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_sku', $parent_sku.'-'.$count );

        }
    }
    if( count($query) < $limit ){
        echo "<p><pre>The job is finished, you can remove the code <br>$count variations SKUs have been updated</pre></p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p><pre>$count variations SKUs have been updated (continue reloading the page again)</pre></p>";
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).*

Tested and works.

Comment: when i put in my functions.php file site return error 500

Comment: ps my site has 30.000 product with 5 variations per product...maybe this is a problem?

Comment: a possible solution?

Comment: maybe i found the problem!!

Comment: if( ! current_user_can('edit_products')) return;
deleted...and error 500 is deleted...and now works!!!

Comment: is there a way to add this functions for a single product that run only when a product will be published??

Comment: message told job finished...but no variations where modified

Comment: i think the easy way to obtain this work is modify the plugin https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-sku-generator/

Comment: does not work. this is the message: The job is finished, you can remove the code
but when i look no one of all item was never changed

Comment: if you can try to help me, i had open another question of about modify woocommerce sku generator...that is really simple!